# Invalid block tag on line 29: 'endfor', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django

Something wrong with my .html template. Can't figure the error on line 29. Says Invalid block tag on line 29: 'endfor', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

```
{%extends 'mtunes/basic.html'%}
{% block title%}Search{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{% load static %} 

{% if query %}
<h1 style="color: rgb(158, 60, 60); text-align: center;">Search Results for {{ query_str }}</h1>


{% for i in query %}
<div class="container">
<div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 940px; padding-top: 0%;">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="/media/{{i.image}}" class="card-img" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="color: green; font-weight: 550;">{{i.name}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Singer Name: {{i.singer}}</p>
          <p class="card-text">Tags: {{i.tags}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">Movie: {{i.movie}}</p>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <a href="/mtunes/songs/{{i.song_id}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Listen Song</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}



  {% elif notfound %}

<div class="row pt-3">
  <!-- you can do a lot more here  -->
  <h1> This song is not Available</h1>
  <span style='font-size:100px;'>&#128514;</span>
</div>

</div>
</div>
{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't ended your `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` tag with an `{% endif %}`

Answer (score 0):

you didn't pass the tag in a right way and there is no such tag name {% elif notfound %} use {% else %} there and close your userauthenciation tag with with {% endif %}

```
{% load static %} 

{% if query %}
<h1 style="color: rgb(158, 60, 60); text-align: center;">Search Results for {{ query_str }}</h1>


{% for i in query %}
<div class="container">
<div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 940px; padding-top: 0%;">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="/media/{{i.image}}" class="card-img" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="color: green; font-weight: 550;">{{i.name}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Singer Name: {{i.singer}}</p>
          <p class="card-text">Tags: {{i.tags}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">Movie: {{i.movie}}</p>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <a href="/mtunes/songs/{{i.song_id}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Listen Song</button></a>
        {% endif %} **you have to close user authentication tag**
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}



  {% else %} **use else here**

<div class="row pt-3">
  <!-- you can do a lot more here  -->
  <h1> This song is not Available</h1>
  <span style='font-size:100px;'>&#128514;</span>
</div>

</div>
</div>
{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```